# Datatable page length selectbox not populating with options when locker service is enabled

Tags: locker-service, datatable

[image: This is the image showing the page with and without locker service]

When we enable the locker service, then the select box is not populating with the options i.e. no option is visible and its not there in dom as well

Comment: What javascript library are you using?

Comment: jQuery Datatable, it has jQuery built in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: This is the DataTable code which creates select box]

**Now The cause of issue**
[image: Locker service disrupts the Option class]
**As seen, new Option is not able to produce the html with locker service enabled**
So I manually created the HTML for the select box and did not add event handlers, since they were already created by datatable of delegated type

> you can find those event handlers by searching "change.dt" in datatable code